# How can I load the content of popover from a php file with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, popover

Here is js code:

```
function bindMyPopovers() {
  $("a[rel=popover]").each(function(){

        $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        html: true,
        title:"Passenger Information",
        content: "Passenger "+$(this).attr('id')+" "+showPassenger($(this).attr('id')) 
    })
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });

});
}
```

And here is the showPassenger() for getting the information of the passengers:

```
var v=false;
function showPassenger(id){
  var id_num=id.charAt(id.length-1);
  $.getJSON('Passengers.php?id='+id_num, function(passenger){
      v=null;

        $.each(passenger, function(pas_key, pas_value) {

          v+=pas_key+" "+pas_value;

        });
      });
   return v;
}
```

When I come to some icon, I can see some information about it(I just controlled).But now, I want to show the content from another file called Passenger.php, but with showPassenger(id) I cannot show the content, and it also doesn't change the value of v.Why is this so?How can I load the content?Thanks.